# Can't get node.js built on cygwin

Tags: node.js

Following the instructions here:

https://github.com/ry/node/wiki/Building-node.js-on-Cygwin-(Windows)

I've tried installing on two machines, either of which I'd be happy to get up and running.

- WinXP

On 'make', I get:

```
Build failed: -> task failed <err #2>:
         {task: libv8.a SConstruct -> libv8.a}
```

According to the instructions, this is caused by having $SHELL set to a Windows style path, but I've set it to /bin/bash and get the same error.

- Win7

On './configure', I get:

```
$ ./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
      0 [main] python 1092 C:\bin\python.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\lib\python2.6\lib-dynload\_functools.dll to same address as parent: 0x360000 != 0x3E0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
002891E8  6102749B  (002891E8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
002894D8  6102749B  (61177B80, 00008000, 00000000, 61179977)
0028A508  61004AFB  (611A136C, 61241CF4, 00360000, 003E0000)
End of stack trace
      0 [main] python 3536 fork: child 1092 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
/Users/Michael/Desktop/node/wscript:177: error: could not configure a c compiler!
```

I've run 'rebaseall' and restarted the machine but still get that error.

Edit: Ok, rebaseall was apparently erroring on some mingw stuff, so I edited the rebaseall script to fix that, and now it configures on Win7. The new problem is that it emits the exact same error as my XP machine now when I try to make. This is on tag v0.3.5.

Comment: i had a similar problem just the other day, but the rebase seemed to solve it. make sure you do like the instructions say - close all other open shells

Comment: All shells were closed. I think it even complains if you have any shells open, although I could be conflating circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried compiling 0.2.5 and it worked. This is a subpar solution, but it'll have to do for now.

Comment: The same worked for me. I'm wondering if there isn't a problem in the latest version.

Comment: There must be. I wish I had time to diagnose and patch it. I wanted to run swank-js on top of node.js, but it fails using cygwin/node 0.2.5.

Comment: I just built 0.5.0pre on cygwin with no issues other than some example code that was buggy. Avoid process.title.